# Get top n records within each group after summing columns

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, group-by

I have a dataset as below

```
df = Col1  Col2  Col3  Col4  
      A      1   10    50%
      A      1   10    25%
      A      2   15    10% 
      A      3   25    15%
      B      1   30    5%
      B      2   40    20%
      B      2   40    25%
      B      3   20    50%
```

I want to group by [Col1,Col2] and sum Col3 and Col4 and then choose the top 2 entry within each group.

I did the following

```
df.groupby(['Col1','Col2])['Col3','Col4'].sum()
```

And the output was

```
 Col1  Col2   Col3  Col4
 A      1      20    75%
        2      15    10%
        3      25    15% 
 B      1      30    5%
        2      80    45%
        3      20    50%
```

However I want the following output with top 2 entry after the sum. how can i get this

```
    Col1  Col2   Col3  Col4
     A      1      20    75%
            3      25    15% 
     B      2      80    45%
            3      20    50%
```

Comment: "top 2" is based on what? Col3?

Comment: No based on Col4

Comment: `df.groupby(['Col1','Col2'])['Col3','Col4'].sum().sort_values(['Col1','Col4'], ascending=False).groupby('Col1').head(2)`.

Comment: Thanks Quang. works perfectly